# What does ~ mean in a Linux shell?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, csh

I'm new to Linux and have been seeing this often. Could someone explain the concept here?

```
~/.somefilename
```

What does the `~` (tilde) signify?

Comment: tilde is the users' home directory

Comment: In any case, this is covered in the appropriate *shell reference*, such as the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Comment: Looks like google does not support it http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2466433

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `~` (tilde) is a quick way of specifying your home directory.

The `~/.somefilename` means your home directory, the file `.somefilename`.

Comment: I should also mention that the . infront of a file name normally signifies it is a hidden file.  It will not show up by default in an ls of a directory unless you specify -a as an option to the ls command.

Answer (score 5):

The tilde ~ character is interpreted by most shells as the "home directory" for you. The "." doesn't mean anything if it's part of a filename, although some programs such as ls will (unless explicitely told otherwise) not show files if their name starts with a "dot". Sort of a "hidden" attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Tilde originally shared the same space on the HOME key of certain keyboards and by association still means home directory.